# How do I switch to a specific git branch and commit id on our staging server

Tags: git, fabric

I want to build into my deployment the ability to checkout the users branch and the commit id he is using.

In the past we only checkout out of master on our deployment boxes.  I did this and it seemed to work.

```
git checkout HASH
```

But now I want the ability to test a branch and hash on our staging boxes.  How do I do that? I thought if I reset to a HASH it would infer the branch but that didn't work.  I thought I could just do a `checkout branch HASH`.

**How can I recreate the users current checkin on his branch on our staging server?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A commit hash by itself does not refer to a branch; it refers to a commit which may be present on multiple branches, or even none at all.

A branch is just a name that points to a commit hash (and this pointer moves as commits are added to the branch).

To check out a branch, you need to use `git checkout <branch>`.

If you are pushing just a hash, you need to switch to pushing a branch by name for the branch name to be known on your staging boxes.

> How can I recreate the users current checkin on his branch on our staging server?

You don't need to check out a branch if this is all you need. Just use `git checkout HASH` as you are already doing. This is guaranteed to always reflect the same thing.

Comment: But how do I checkout a commit ID along a branch?

Comment: Just check out the commit ID as you are already doing. See the DETACHED HEAD section of the git-checkout manpage if this doesn't make sense to you. Understanding git's data model will really help you here.

Comment: ✓ read the detached state on git man page.  Does this mean that I can safely ignore the branch name always and just focus on the commit ID?

Answer (score 1):

### This Requires Multiple Commands

Except in the special case of creating a new branch, the the *checkout* command can't take both a branch ref and a commit hash at the same time. So, to checkout a commit on a different branch as a detached head:

```
git checkout <branch_name>
git checkout <commit_hash>
```

### Identical Hashes are Identical Commits

The above may not be strictly necessary since (from a practical point of view) an identical commit hash contains the same contents regardless of the branch it is on. For example, commit 1d2cad0 can exist on multiple branches, and for detached heads it shouldn't matter which branch you're on when you `git checkout` that commit.

For example, if 1d2cad0 exists on branch *foo*, you can `git checkout 1d2cad0` from *any* branch and you will receive a message similar to the following:

> HEAD is now at 6bce656... foo

You are in a detached head, and will see additional instructions about how to handle that. For this use case, you really don't need to worry about branches *per se* until and unless you want to make additional commits that will require git to track ancestry.

Comment: I think I'm starting to get it..  If the checkout only exist in a single branch when you `git checkout <commit_hash>` does that imply the branch?  So why checkout the branch_name?

Comment: The second `git checkout` in your example will completely wipe out the effects of the first. You don't need the first one there at all.

Comment: So can I ignore the branch_name altogether and simply work off off the current hash? Will that recreate the same structure on the staging server as the one I am working off of?

Comment: @rh0dium A commit hash reflects the entire tree at the time of the commit, so your working directory should be updated to match the tree stored in that commit unless the current working directory isn't clean.